# Num day to Name day with Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dayofweek, weekday

If I use this funtion `pd.DatetimeIndex(dfTrain['datetime']).weekday` I get number of the day, but I don't find any function which give the name of de day... So I need to convert 0 to Monday, 1 to Tuestday and so on.

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
            datetime    season holiday workingday weather   temp    atemp   humidity    windspeed   count
    0   2011-01-01 00:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  81  0.0000  16
    1   2011-01-01 01:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0.0000  40
    2   2011-01-01 02:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0.0000  32
    3   2011-01-01 03:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  75  0.0000  13
    4   2011-01-01 04:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  75  0.0000  1
    5   2011-01-01 05:00:00 1   0   0   2   9.84    12.880  75  6.0032  1
    6   2011-01-01 06:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.02    13.635  80  0.0000  2
    7   2011-01-01 07:00:00 1   0   0   1   8.20    12.880  86  0.0000  3
    8   2011-01-01 08:00:00 1   0   0   1   9.84    14.395  75  0.0000  8
    9   2011-01-01 09:00:00 1   0   0   1   13.12   17.425  76  0.0000  14
```

Another question more, which is the difference between `pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek`and `pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday`?

Comment: so why not use a 7-tuple with the names of the day?

Comment: You can get an array of localised day names from [calendar.day_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One method, so long as datetime is already a datetime column is to apply `datetime.strftime` to get the string for the weekday:

```
In [105]:

df['weekday'] = df[['datetime']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x['datetime'], '%A'), axis=1)
df
Out[105]:
             datetime  season  holiday  workingday  weather   temp   atemp  \
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
5 2011-01-01 05:00:00       1        0           0        2   9.84  12.880   
6 2011-01-01 06:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
7 2011-01-01 07:00:00       1        0           0        1   8.20  12.880   
8 2011-01-01 08:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
9 2011-01-01 09:00:00       1        0           0        1  13.12  17.425   

   humidity  windspeed  count   weekday  
0        81     0.0000     16  Saturday  
1        80     0.0000     40  Saturday  
2        80     0.0000     32  Saturday  
3        75     0.0000     13  Saturday  
4        75     0.0000      1  Saturday  
5        75     6.0032      1  Saturday  
6        80     0.0000      2  Saturday  
7        86     0.0000      3  Saturday  
8        75     0.0000      8  Saturday  
9        76     0.0000     14  Saturday
```

As to your other question, there is no difference between `dayofweek` and `weekday`.

It will be quicker to define a map of the weekday to String equivalent and call map on the weekday:

```
dayOfWeek={0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday', 2:'Wednesday', 3:'Thursday', 4:'Friday', 5:'Saturday', 6:'Sunday'}
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.dayofweek.map(dayOfWeek)
```

For version prior to `0.15.0` the following should work:

```
import datetime as dt
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%A'))
```

**Version 0.18.1 and newer**

There is now a new convenience method [`dt.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html) to do the above

**Version 0.23.0 and newer**

weekday_name is now depricated in favour of [`dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html).

Answer (score 24):

Using `dt.weekday_name` is [deprecated since `pandas 0.23.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name.html), instead, use [`dt.day_name()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
df.datetime.dt.day_name()

0    Saturday
1    Saturday
2    Saturday
3    Saturday
4    Saturday
5    Saturday
6    Saturday
7    Saturday
8    Saturday
9    Saturday
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 21):

Last versions you can use [`dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.day_name
print df
             datetime  season  holiday  workingday  weather   temp   atemp  \
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
5 2011-01-01 05:00:00       1        0           0        2   9.84  12.880   
6 2011-01-01 06:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.02  13.635   
7 2011-01-01 07:00:00       1        0           0        1   8.20  12.880   
8 2011-01-01 08:00:00       1        0           0        1   9.84  14.395   
9 2011-01-01 09:00:00       1        0           0        1  13.12  17.425   

   humidity  windspeed  count   weekday  
0        81     0.0000     16  Saturday  
1        80     0.0000     40  Saturday  
2        80     0.0000     32  Saturday  
3        75     0.0000     13  Saturday  
4        75     0.0000      1  Saturday  
5        75     6.0032      1  Saturday  
6        80     0.0000      2  Saturday  
7        86     0.0000      3  Saturday  
8        75     0.0000      8  Saturday  
9        76     0.0000     14  Saturday
```

Comment: Link is broken (404).

Comment: Series.dt.day_name is implemented as a method, not an attribute. As such you need to call it with ()
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.day_name()

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous **correct** answer from @jezrael, you can use this:

```
import calendar
df['weekday'] = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(df['datetime'].dt.weekday_name, categories=list(calendar.day_name)))
```

which also provides your new categorical variable with **order** (in this example: 'Monday', ..., 'Sunday')  according to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#working-with-categories). This will possibly be helpful on next steps of your analysis.